# Работа с внешней памятью в keil uvision

Tags: ассемблер, компиляция, микроконтроллеры

Допустим, моя программа работает с внешней памятью.
Каждый раз заполнять руками ячейки внешней памяти крайне проблематично.
Можно ли как-нибудь в keil uvision из какого-нибудь txt файла заполнить ячейки внешней памяти?